# Mute windows 10 master volume using C# in .NET Core or UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

Anyone know how to programmatically mute the Windows 10 Volume using C# in .NET Core or in Universal Windows platform.
I searched a lot but couldn't find any straight forward standard API for this in .NET Core for windows UWP Apps.

Comment: take a look at https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

Comment: or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c53b704-e252-4d8a-b8b9-df4ad3986d4a/how-to-reduce-system-volume?forum=csharpgeneral . The last answer seems to be working

Comment: Any update available for .Net Core?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically about UWP, the following links might be of some value to you:

- [Sound in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/sound);
- [Audio and Video with MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer);

**However as the links's description might indicate, it only explains how we can control the sound inside the application**, either by controlling the integrated sound system in UWP, or the audio in a control such as `MediaPlayer`.

For instance, imagining that it isn't desired to have any kind off sound in an UWP app, we could perform the following *set*:

```
ElementSoundPlayer.State = ElementSoundPlayerState.Off;
```

However, when it comes to actually override the System's Volume, that does not seem possible. As it is mentioned in the documentation, the app's sound can't get any louder than the system's sound. In this example,

```
ElementSoundPlayer.Volume = 1.0;
```

The `Volume` property has been set to it's maximum value, but that only means that the sound volume will be the same as the system's volume.

The API does not seem to provide a way to directly change the System's Volume. It's all about the ecosystem of the app itself being managed by the system and not the opposite.